# javax.el.PropretyNotWritableException: The class Article does not have a writable property 'id'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have an Article DTO (Article.java; code excerpts)

```
public class Article {

private int id;

public Article() {
    this.id = 0;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

I got a view template for editing the article (edit_article.xhtml; code excerpts):

```
            <h:form id="article_form">
                <p:messages id="messages"/>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                    <h:inputHidden id="articleId" value="#{hqArticleView.article.id}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
```

and I have a view backing bean (HqArticleView.java; code excerpts):

```
@Named("hqArticleView")
@RequestScoped
public class HqArticleView implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Logger log;

@Inject
private IArticleService articleService;

private Article article;
private List<Article> articles;
private Map<String, String> requestParams;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    requestParams = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    article = new Article();
    article.setPublish(true);

    if (requestParams.containsKey("id")) {
        article.setId(Integer.parseInt(requestParams.get("id")));
        article = articleService.getArticle(article);
    }
}

public Article getArticle() {
    return article;
}

public void setArticle(Article article) {
    this.article = article;
}

public List<Article> getArticles() {
    articles = articleService.getAll();
    Collections.reverse(articles);
    return articles;
}

public void save() {
    log.debug("save pressed");
}

public void edit(Article article) {
    log.debug("edit pressed | id=" + article.getId());
}

public void delete(Article article) {
    log.debug("delete pressed | id=" + article.getId());
}
}
```

The problem is: I try to access the view I'm getting an error: The class Article does not have a writable property 'id'.
all other fields from the Article are processed correctly, only the id is a problem.
Strange is, when I wrap the id getter and setter of the Article object inside the bean in:

```
public void setId(int id){
    this.article.setId(id);
}

public int getId(){
    return this.article.getId();
}
```

then it works perfectly. what am I missing?

Comment: At quick glance, you have some inconsistency of data types in field/getter/setter for "id": once it's "int", once it's "Integer". Could you try changing all of them to "Integer" and check if it helps?

Comment: thx, that was the problem. very dumb mistake

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When examing the property type for reading, EL looks at the return type of the getter:

```
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
```

It's thus of type `Integer`. When EL needs to write the changed value, EL is expecting a setter taking the same type:

```
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

However, no such setter exists in your `Article` class. Instead, you've a setter taking an `int`. That's exactly why EL threw a `PropertyNotWritableException`. It means that it couldn't find a matching setter taking exactly the same type. Fix it accordingly by using `Integer` instead of `int` in the setter (or, in this particular case better, by using `int` instead of `Integer` in the getter).

That it worked when you exploded the model in the controller (bad practice by the way) is because the getter and setter matched each other.

Comment: *argh* thats dumb. to be honest i don't know why there was type Integer... but that was the problem. thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

sometimes is the problem in the name of the variable so need to try another name to solve this issue !